# why the result of jmap -histo is different from jmap -dump

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

recently i met a gc problem ,i used jmap to dump out the heap. But unfortunately it did not work properly;

i run jmap -histo 3916|more  before dump ,the result is

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:       1784198      733117168  [C
   2:      12210014      390720448  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
   3:      11908601      285806424  java.lang.Long
   4:      11884602      285230448  java.lang.Double
   5:           545       86335608  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;
   6:         12405       65677584  [I
   7:       1735496       41651904  java.lang.String
```

then i ran "jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin 3916", and then i used eclipse  MemoryAnalyzer to analyze heap.bin,which produced a histogram as below

```
Class Name                                   |    Objects | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node  | 12,207,879 |  390,652,128 |              
java.lang.Long                               | 11,889,204 |  285,340,896 |              
java.lang.Double                             | 11,884,164 |  285,219,936 |              
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]|        347 |   86,311,832 |              
char[]                                       |  1,659,912 |   50,128,128 |              
java.lang.String                             |  1,659,062 |   39,817,488 |              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Analyzed the two result, i  found that the objects in dump are all less than histo,and
the Objects  of char[]  is much less, but why? does jmap trigger a minor gc when  run  "jmap -dump"  command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jmap` does not trigger GC unless you specify `:live` option. Without this option the histogram includes unreachable objects.

However, Memory Analyzer by default [removes unreachable objects](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_analyse_unreachable_objects) while parsing a heap dump. Though it is possible to count unreachable objects with Memory Analyzer, too.